# Equivalence of MS Graph User Id and Azure AD Object Identifier claim?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

The user object returned by the [MS Graph Users API](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user) has an id field that appears to be the same as the [Azure AD ObjectIdentifier (oid](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-token-and-claims/#idtokens)) claim.  Is this a documented and reliable correspondence, or if I want to obtain the object identifier, should I go through the Azure AD Graph Users API instead of the MS Graph Users API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the ids are the same. Here is guidance on Microsoft Graph vs Azure AD Graph: http://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph

Comment: Thanks Yina!  Would it be possible to point me to something that documents that the user Id field is the same as the object identifier claim?

Comment: We don't have any documentation on this currently (i.e. the "renaming" of the AAD Graph properties in the Microsoft Graph).  Many properties were renamed so that we have more consistent naming across Microsoft Graph.